# Magento display selected out of stock product on front end

Tags: magento

I would like to display few of 'out of stock' product on front end catalog page.
I know we can show all 'out of stock' product by setting from

> system->configuration->inventory.

How can I show few of the out of stock product on front end.
I was thinking to add a custom attribute say 'show_out_of_stock' and when its value is **'yes'**, by adding some if-else condition I could display **'selected out of stock'** product.

But this solution create problem with pagination as I am not changing any thing in **'product collection'**.

Another idea i was thinking to modify **'Product Collection'** according to requirement.

Please let me know if there is any better solution for this?

Comment: You want to show few out of stock products with available  products??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every product in magento has visibility.

If you want to make specific products visible on frontend, make visibility attribute as "catalog" or "catalog/search".

This will be independent of the stock availability of the products. Products which you do not want to show, you can make it "not visible individually".

If your visibility is dynamic based on some external factor or orders, you can add a cron (Automated process which runs every specified time) in which you can change  the visibility of products accordingly.

:)

Comment: Thank you for your reply Ravi. As far as I understand whether product's visibility is "catalog" or "catalog/search", the stock should be greater than 0 to display products on front end,

Comment: You want to show few out of stock products with available products?? 
  - yes, you are correct.

Comment: You can also show out of stock products in frontend, depending on their visibility. You can configure it in system-configuration-catalog